# How to set unit test jvmargs using gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to set jvmargs for unit tests using kotlin-dsl and I can't get it to work.

This is so that I can add the "-noverify" argument and allow intellji test runner to collect code coverage info.

Groovy, works:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
    }
```

Kotlin, doesn't work:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all(KotlinClosure1<Any, Test>({
            (this as Test).also { jvmArgs("-noverify") }
        }, this))
    }
```

This too:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all(KotlinClosure1<Any, Test>({
            (this as Test).also { jvmArgs = listOf("-noverify") }
        }, this))
    }
```

Nothing seems to work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

This question is a little old but wanted to post an updated Kotlin DSL version for 2021:

```
testOptions.unitTests.all { it.jvmArgs("-noverify") }
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue. The following snippet works.

```
tasks.withType<Test>().all {
    jvmArgs("-noverify")
}
```

Ref - https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#jvmArgs-java.lang.Object...-

Verified using Gradle-5.1.-all version